# R for-loop for varibles in ftp address

Tags: r, for-loop, ftp, zip

I want to get multiple zip files from a ftp server.
I can get the zip files individually with the help of previous posts.

But that would be a lot of work for all needed data. So I wantet to find an automated way.

The ftp looks like this:
ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/10_minutes/solar/now/10minutenwerte_SOLAR_01048_now.zip

I want to change the "01048" to the ID of the nearest wheater station, whitch I have in a data frame (data) already.

I thought I can just for loop all the needed stations

```
for(y in Data$StationsID)) {
  urls <- "ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/10_minutes/solar/now/10minutenwerte_SOLAR_{y}_now.zip"))
}
```

but I only get "ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/10_minutes/solar/now/10minutenwerte_SOLAR_{y}_now.zip"))

the zip data holds an.txt ideal for csv analysis.

Later I want to use the files to get solar data from diffrent points in Germany.
But firts I need a list like this but I don't know how to get that:

```
urls
[1] url_1
[2] url_2
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not even need a loop. Try

```
urls <- paste0("ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/10_minutes/solar/now/10minutenwerte_SOLAR_", Data$StationsID, "_now.zip")
```

This will give you a vector of all URLs.
Afterwards you can fetch all files using e.g. `lapply`.

```
results <- lapply(urls, FUN = function(u) {
  # FETCH
  # UNZIP
  # TIDY
  # ...
}
```

Comment: I  could get all the urls I needed, but I can't get the function to display them correctly. I only get the last element. I thougt of something like this: runterladenundentzippen = function(u) 
  {
  
  destfile = "newzipfile.zip"
  
  fileList <- unzip(destfile , list = TRUE)
  solarName <- fileList$"Name"
  unzip(destfile)
}

Comment: With this function you have not downloaded any file yet.

Answer (score 0):

( first question!)

An alternate approach is below.

We:

- get all the possible data files
- filter it to just the SOLAR zip data files (you could filter more if needed — i.e. restrict it to what you have in your existing data frame)
- make a save location
- download the files

Note that it is really bad form to hammer a server with consecutive requests without a pause so this introduces that but that's an oft overlooked courtesy these days.

```
library(curl)
library(httr)

base_dir <- "ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/10_minutes/solar/now/"

# Get all available files in that directory
res <- curl_fetch_memory(base_dir, handle = new_handle(dirlistonly = TRUE)

grep(
  "SOLAR_[[:digit:]]{5}",
  strsplit(rawToChar(res$content), "\n")[[1]], # curl_fetch returns a raw vector since it has no idea what type of content might be there so we have to convert it and it's a text listing so we have to do some more wrangling
  value = TRUE
) -> all_zips

head(all_zips)
## [1] "10minutenwerte_SOLAR_00044_now.zip"
## [2] "10minutenwerte_SOLAR_00071_now.zip"
## [3] "10minutenwerte_SOLAR_00073_now.zip"
## [4] "10minutenwerte_SOLAR_00131_now.zip"
## [5] "10minutenwerte_SOLAR_00150_now.zip"
## [6] "10minutenwerte_SOLAR_00154_now.zip"

save_dir <- "~/Data/solar-output"

dir.create(save_dir)

for (zip in all_zips) {
  try(httr::GET(
    url = sprintf("%s%s", base_dir, zip),
    httr::write_disk(file.path(save_dir, zip)), # enables caching (it won't overwrite by default and avoid issues with download.file() on windows)
    httr::progress() # progress bars for free!
  ))
  Sys.sleep(5) # be kind to their server CPU and network bandwidth
}
```

We wrap the `GET()` in `try()` since we've asked `write_disk()` to *not* overwrite existing files. It tosses an exception when this happens so `try()` catches it and lets the loop keep going (but still displays the helpful message about the file already existing).